# Проблема с расчетом даты в google scripts

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Доброго времени суток!

В гугл таблицах у меня создан скрипт, который нужен чтобы автоматически высчитывать дату завершения заказа основываясь на дате отправки, конкретном исполнителе и виде работы.
Скрипт на первый взгляд работает, однако проблема появляется когда изначальная дата выходит за пределы текущего месяца. Так, например, если суммарный срок выполнения заказа 5 дней, дата отправки - 31.08.2018 и текущий месяц у нас соответственно сентябрь, дата завершения рассчитается как 04.10(!).2018.
И наоборот, при тех же параметрах и дате отправки 1.10.2018 дата завершения рассчитается как 06.09(!).2018

Я еще новичок в javascript и не могу понять почему так происходит. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема.

Функция которая рассчитывает дату и вызывается в onEdit ячеек даты, исполнителя и вида работы:

```
function modifyDate(){

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Лаборатории');
  var datasheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Цены и сроки');
  var ColumnC = sheet.getRange(2, 3, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1); //вид работы
  var cValues = ColumnC.getValues();
  var ColumnD = sheet.getRange(2, 4, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1); //исполнитель
  var dValues = ColumnD.getValues();
  var ColumnA = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1); //дата отправки
  var aValues = ColumnA.getValues();
  //столбец N с отметкой о завершении заказа для проверки в условии
  var ColumnN = sheet.getRange(2, 14, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1); 
  var nValues = ColumnN.getValues();
  var cdek = 6;

  var i2date = new Date();

 var Ivanov = datasheet.getRange('I1').getValue(); //фамилия исполнителя
 var R5 = datasheet.getRange('A2').getValue(); //вид работы
 var I2 = datasheet.getRange('I2').getValue(); //соответствующее количество дней

for (var i = 0; i < aValues.length; i++) {
    var aData = new Date(aValues[i][0]);
    var cData = new String(cValues[i][0]);
    var dData = new String(dValues[i][0]);
    var nData = new String(nValues[i][0]);

    if (cData == R5 && dData == Ivanov && I2!='' && nData == '') {
    i2date.setDate(aData.getDate()+cdek+I2);
    sheet.getRange(i + 2, 11, 1, 1).setValues([[i2date]])}
    else {}
}

function onEdit(event){

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Лаборатории');
  var range = event.range;

  if (range.getRow() >= 2 && range.getColumn() == 1){
  modifyDate();
  } else {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для прозрачного расчета дат в js используйте манипуляции с миллисекундами. Например, добавление 30 дней к текущей дате:

```
var date = new Date();
var date30 = new Date(date.getTime() + 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

Такой подход обезопасит вас от проблем типа `i2date.setDate(aData.getDate() + cdek + I2);`, связанных с подсчетами дней, месяцев и лет.

Comment: И можно почитать любую статью про даты JS. Например тут - https://learn.javascript.ru/datetime#автоисправление-даты